# Is there any way to know when a driver is near retirement?

Tags: motorsport-manager

There is a tip in loading screen saying something like this:

> If a driver is near retiring, he/she will decline new contract

Is there a way to know when a driver is planning to retire? It might be useful to access this information while scouting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to access this information is by receiving an in-game mail (Media section).

[image]

On a side note, as I can see from my experience, this kind of mail is more likely top appear during pre-season weeks.